# return type of who_user in scilab

Tags: variables, memory-management, pseudocode, scilab

I work with scilab, but during a project, scilab has to deal with a large number of variables.
I was wondering if i can do the following

```
var_list = who_user();
for _var_ = var_list do
  if _var_ is global then
    writetofile(human_readablefile, _var_)
  end
end
clear()
```

of course this is a pseudocode, and i have a few questions before i implement it.

1. I can not get var_list = who_user() working. so i believe the function does not return anything. I am reluctant to hack into the code of the "who_user" macro itself. Is there any other way to get the list of user variables in another variable?
2. Is there a way to find the global variables out of them?
3. If not, then what are some memory management techniques in scilab?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to answer your first query:

From a slight modification of the who_user function itself:

```
function nams = who_user1()
  //get user variables
  [nams,mem]=who('get'); //get all variables
  p=predef(); //number of system variable
  st=stacksize()
  nams=nams(1:$-p+1);mem=mem(1:$-p+1);
  //modifiable system variables
  excluded=['demolist','scicos_pal','%scicos_menu',..
    '%scicos_short','%helps','%helps_modules','MSDOS','who_user','%scicos_display_mode', ...
      '%scicos_help'];
  ke=grep(nams,excluded)
  nams(ke)=[];mem(ke)=[];

  n=size(nams,1);
  if n==0 then return,end

  //format names on n*10 characters
  ll=length(nams)+2;m=int((ll-1)/10)+1;
  for k=1:max(m)
    ks=find(m==k);
    if ks<>[] then nams(ks)=part(nams(ks),1:(k*10));end
  end
endfunction
```

This function should give you the list you desire (I have modified the name to who_user1).

You can find out whether a specific variable is global or not by using the isglobal() function, but you need to pass a variable to isglobal(), not the string that is the name of the variable. The function I've listed above returns a vector of strings.

An alternative approach you could try would be to rewrite the above function to return the variables (rather than their names) directly using varargout and then testing them for being globals.

Comment: thanks , http://www.scilab.org/product/man/getvariablesonstack.html is ehat i was actually looking for